# how to install software on linux without root permissions

Tags: linux

I need some help to install the ABySS assembler on PuTTY (virtual Linux) without root permission (as it takes a long time going via IT department etc.).
To be honest I've no idea where to start from, so I'll be very appreciated for step-by-step guide if that is not too much to ask.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know that it's necessary to get StackOverflow's help if all you want to do is circumvent your IT department's policies. Are you sure there's not an easier way to get fired if that's what you want?

Comment: Installing programs into a user's home directory isn't a ridiculous things to do. There are millions of virtual web servers out there putting Perl modules etc. into a local path. User separation exists for a reason. Can you provide a link to the software in question and the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: There is a link to a software: http://www.bcgsc.ca/platform/bioinfo/software/abyss

Comment: I  upvoted the question in order for it not to dismissed, as I agree with @IanGibbs. However you need to edit adding more details. The site has the source for you to compile. What packages would you need to install that are not available? (use the source, Luke!) What  distribution is used on the server? Putty is not "virtual linux", it gives you a terminal (most probably through ssh) on a remote server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the software [here](https://github.com/bcgsc/abyss), then it should be sufficient to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/bcgsc/abyss#compiling-abyss-from-source). Specifically, you should take note of the part labelled **To install ABySS in a specified directory:**, and specify a directory in your home directory that you have write access to. For example, I might:

```
mkdir ~/abyss
./configure --prefix=$HOME/abyss
make
make install
```

Note that I have removed `sudo` from before `make install`, so that you are trying to run the installation as a user rather than root. `make install` will put the software wherever you specified with `--prefix`.

However, this all depends upon the source code for any libraries upon which ABySS depends existing on your system as well. I expect you will fail at the `./configure` step because some library is missing. In this case download the source code for those libraries and tell configure where you have put them (in your home directory), following the example given for Boost on that same page.